Do countries at war always treat each other's diplomats as personae non gratae?
On December 7, 1941, Japan launched surprise attacks against the U.S. naval bases at Pearl Harbor, Wake Island, and the Philippines, and on that same day Japan's diplomats in Washington were declared personae non gratae.
I have long more-or-less unthinkingly assumed such expulsion of diplomats just after the commencement of a war is how it's always done, if there are diplomats to expel. But now I remember that in 1782, when Britain and France were at war against each other, France admitted British diplomats whose purpose was to negotiate with American diplomats in Paris. The U.S.A. was then allied with France. In November 1782, when the British and American negotiators agreed on the content of a peace treaty, they called the document the "preliminary articles of peace" rather than calling it a proposed peace treaty to be submitted to higher authorities in both countries for approval. (Maybe I'm mistaken, but I think) that was because a treaty between the U.S.A. and France signed in 1778 said that neither would conclude a separate peace with Britain, and France was still at war with Britain.
One can imagine a diplomat from an enemy country being admitted in order to discuss whether peace can be concluded if a certain agreement on an international boundary can be reached or to discuss details of an exchange of prisoners of war, or perhaps for some other purposes.
What are current usages concerning admission of diplomats from enemy countries?

I am not sure if I would count a surprise attack declaring the war as a normal situation.

@JoeW : I hope my subsequent edit clarifies.

I'd expect these to be handled on a case-by-case basis.

I only see a single case of diplomats being considered PNG and it was the surprise attack I mentioned before. The case with British/French/American diplomats doesn't seem to be a case of PNG rather them gathering diplomats to negotiate a treaty. It is easily possibly that there was diplomats in France already but they were not the ones needed for the negotiations. Even if it was the case that they did get made PNG during that time two cases isn't enough to make a judgement about how it normally works.

@JoeW : I would expect that persons who answer the question (i.e. those who "make a judgement about how it normally works") would know far more than those two cases.

@JoeW : Did you understand that what I posted was intended to be understood as a question rather than as an answer?

I think you are not understanding what I am saying. You gave a single example that doesn’t suggest that it is a pattern of how countries always treat diplomats in a time of war. As was mentioned in another comment this is very likely to be highly situational depending upon the countries and situations. There is unlikely to be a single answer for this question.

I would expect that almost always diplomatic personal is returned to their origin countries; you do not want a group of employees from the enemy power who have the right to communicate freely with their government in your soil providing information. The example you quote is about a reduced group of diplomats entering for a limited time and a very specific task that can be done at a very specific location, possibly with security restrictions. Very different from keeping an open embassy at your capital, a few hundreds from your government office.

Maybe you could rephrase "I remember that in 1782" , unless you are 240+ years old. Maybe something like "I remember reading that in 1782"

@Prem : I remember that Julius Caesar was assassinated in 44 BC. That doesn't mean I remember the assassination; it means I remember that it is a fact that it happened.

No worries , that was just a Suggestion : Instead of "I remember it rained the night I was born" , I might have said something like "I remember my mother telling me that it rained the night I was born" , @MichaelHardy , though that is a "Personal Choice" & not a mandatory rule !

The outbreak of war is by definition the end of diplomatic relations. By international convention, diplomats are expelled from the host nation (in the rare cases where they haven't been pulled by their own nations), not imprisoned as enemy combatants. The nations involved can still negotiate a diplomatic presence for limited and particular purposes, essentially the age-old practice of sending someone to parlay with an enemy. However, they don't allow a permanent diplomatic presence because that would have no positive purpose and would create a potential hub for espionage.

"The outbreak of war is by definition the end of diplomatic relations." -- except you say later that it isn't. Which also makes me baffled by the certainty that a continuing diplomatic presence "would have no positive purpose".

@Sneftel: Nations use diplomacyinstead of warfare; diplomacy settles international disputes without armed conflict. If war breaks out, diplomacy has ipso facto failed. Once war is declared, normal diplomacy has no power (because the element of mutual trust necessary for diplomacy has vanished). Bur nations are still capable of respecting diplomatic norms for specific and well-defined purposes.

@Sneftel: This is just psychology. If you dislike someone, you can still work with them (that's diplomacy); If you hate someone with a passion you can't work with them (that's war)), but you can still agree to cooperate on certain things. The difference is between having diplomatic rations (normalized channels of regular communication) and allowing occasional ad hoc diplomacy (communications that serve particular purposes).

That would explain why a political leader so consumed with personal animus as to make them irrational might behave that way, and I don’t doubt that it’s a common phenomenon, but I don’t see why it should be a given. What law of nature would make it impossible to have “regular” communication between two warring states?

Certainly it is not unusual for diplomats from countries at war with each other meet to negotiate in a neutral country. Sometimes it is for the purpose of discussing how to end the war, as when Ukrainian and Russian diplomats met in Turkey or when American and North Vietnamese diplomats met in Paris. Sometimes the purpose is to arrange exchanges of prisoners of war. So war does not always mean all diplomacy has ceased.

@Sneftel: You overestimate the rationality of world leaders (and human beings in general). One doesn't need personal animus to be distrusting or paranoid, and when a nation begins a war its foremost representatives are not generally viewed kindly.  The only reason we had this issue in 1941, I think, is that Japan began the war with a surprise attack, and didn't want to telegraph its intentions by pulling its diplomats beforehand.

"Nations use diplomacyinstead of warfare; diplomacy settles international disputes without armed conflict. If war breaks out, diplomacy has ipso facto failed."  Argument by definition is poor rhetoric. Even if you could convince me to adopt a definition of "diplomacy" that is incompatible with war (and there really isn't much point in trying to debate about definitions), then such a definition would have to be so narrow that having an embassy would not necessarily fall under it. You also don't seem to distinguish between war and total war.

@Acccumulation: You don't seem to grasp the distinction here between formal diplomatic relationships and ad hoc diplomacy; the first ends at the outbreak of war, the second can occur anytime. Argument by nit-picking is also poor rhetoric, you know…

@TedWrigley You present no explanation whatsoever for what distinction you think there is, or how I don't grasp it, or any explanation for how I'm "nitpicking".

@Acccumulation: Well, I'm glad we agree on something.


The functions of a diplomatic mission consist, inter alia, in representing the sending State in the receiving State; protecting in the receiving State the interests of the sending State and of its nationals, within the limits permitted by international law; negotiating with the Government of the receiving State; ascertaining by all lawful means conditions and developments in the receiving State, and reporting thereon to the Government of the sending State; promoting friendly relations between the sending State and the receiving State, and developing their economic, cultural and scientific relations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diplomatic_mission#Role

Pretty few if any of those roles would still be welcomed between countries at war. They could still be in contact with each other, but diplomatic relations and diplomatic missions usually mean to imply a closer cooperative relation than just continue talking. Also those talks might not even be done by diplomats of the respective country directly but either by neutral states or take place in neutral states.
The thing is there are various practical problems with the diplomats remaining in that country. On the one hand they are basically perfect spies (some probably already are), but in general they are granted immunity from crime cannot be molested, imprisoned or otherwise be mistreated just send home and they are free to regularly and secretly talk to their sending country and exchange information uninhibited and without surveillance. So they have at the very least access to the cultural climate, the public announcements, the propaganda narratives and where any information could be of value that can be dangerous for the host country, while on the other hand they might have authority to negotiate on behalf of the sending country yet are in another hostile country, where they could be coerced and where their vulnerable position could be exploited. That would be highly illegal, but to monitor that would be difficult.
So according to this answer from the history stack the usual course of action is to lock down the embassy hand it over to neutral country and allow the diplomats to leave the country via a neutral 3rd party.
The thing is even in war when you might say "what are they going to do, go to war over it?", diplomats are still expected to be treated correctly because the international community protects their rights due to their vulnerable position which includes that of their own diplomatic missions. So mistreating diplomats could be seen as an act of war not just against that country but against the internal community and might get much more countries involved.
Also yeah personae non gratae is the plural of persona non grata.


On December 7, 1941, Japan launched surprise attacks against the U.S. naval bases at Pearl Harbor, Wake Island, and the Philippines, and on that same day Japan's diplomats in Washington were declared personae non gratae.

There's some backstory that helps answer the question in general. The Japanese Ambassador at the time was Kichisaburō Nomura

The retired Admiral, and in fact the entire Japanese Foreign Office, was kept in the dark as to the Japanese Navy's impending attack upon Pearl Harbor. Nomura and Kurusu had to decode the radioed message of Japan's breaking off of the negotiations with the United States, which practically meant war. It was sent from Japan on Monday, December 8, Japan time, and received while the Washington embassy's technical support staff were still on their Sunday off. Nomura stated that was why he was unable to deliver the message until after the actual attack had taken place.

Normally, when war breaks out, ambassadors and their entourage are expelled from the country. In the case of Nomura, he was sent a message basically declaring war, and had the ignominy of taking too long to decode it. He delivered it long after the attack on Pearl Harbor had started.
Both he and the US ambassador were held until there could be an exchange, which did not happen until later in the war. Neither were mistreated, just under a sort of house arrest.

What are current usages concerning admission of diplomats from enemy countries?

While Russia isn't at war with everyone, the Ukrainian War has prompted many countries to expel Russian diplomats, most of whom are NATO members

The Russian invasion of Ukraine in 2022 resulted in an unprecedented reaction in diplomatic circles against Russian diplomats; over 200 were expelled by 5 April 2022, just days after the disclosure of the killing of civilians in the Bucha massacre. The declared intention was to limit Russia's ability to destabilize the EU and NATO countries.


"Neither were mistreated" I wonder if we will soon be at the point where this will be considered standard English usage, instead of "Neither was mistreated." In recent years I've seen this several times from respectable writers.

I think they didn't expel any ambassadors of Russia then, just the 'extra' personnel, which is often suspected of espionage etc.

The normal way is that the diplomats go away on the spot, at most in one or two days. They might remain longer only in an extraordinary reason, for example if the country does not consider the war declaration really serious.
Reason is very simple, you are there to talk with them, but they are coming to kill you.
